# PowerShell - Assistance needed with Regex with named capture groups

Tags: regex, powershell

Good Evening,

I am trying to teach myself regex and running into an issue trying to figure this out. I have 3 days worth of logs that will look similar to below.

I am capturing the information into named capture groups and then adding in powershell to an array list.

Problems, I need to ignore everything between `<` `>`, I don't need it.

Then I need to look ahead and see if it is `Added`, `Deleted` or `Updated`, ignoring the `Configuration` part. Then return the match if it is one of those 3. Then skip `BY USER` and just grab the user name.

The final result should look like this from regex perspective:

```
Date    09 Dec 2020
Time    12:59:28
ErrorID VPSa0217I
PrintQ  PRINTQUEUE1
Action  UPDATED
User    op9p99
```

Logfile containing records like these:

```
09 Dec 2020 12:59:28 VPSa0217I <CREQ0009        > PRINTQUEUE1 ADDED BY USER op9p99
09 Dec 2020 13:00:22 VPSa0219I <CREQ0011        > PRINTQUEUE1 CONFIGURATION UPDATED BY USER op9p99
09 Dec 2020 14:20:59 VPSa0217I <CREQ0014        > PRINTQUEUE1 DELETED BY USER op9p99
```

Tried:

```sh
#$Regex1 = "(?<Date>\d{2}\s[ADFJMNOS][a-z]{2,8}\s[12][0-9]{3}\b)\s(?<Time>(?!\s)\d+:\d+:\d+).(?<ErrorID>[VPSa]{2,4}\d{4}[A-Z])(?<Junk>.<.*?>.*?\s)(?<PrintQ>\w+)(?<Action>.\bADDED|DELETED|UPDATED\b)(?<Junk2>\s\w+\s\w+\s)(?<User>\w+)"
    
#$Regex2 = "(?<Date>\d{2}\s[ADFJMNOS][a-z]{2,8}\s[12][0-9]{3}\b)(?<Time>\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(?<ErrorID>[VPSa]{2,4}\d{4}[A-Z])(?<Junk>.<.*?>.*?\s)(?<PrintQ>\w+)(?<Action>\s\bADDED|DELETED|UPDATED\b)(?<Junk2>\s\w+\s\w+\s)(?<User>\w+)"
    
$regex3 = "(?<Date>\d{2}\s[ADFJMNOS][a-z]{2,8}\s[12][0-9]{3}\b)(?<Time>\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(?<ErrorID>[VPSa]{2,4}\d{4}[A-Z])(?<Junk>.<.*?>.*?\s)(?<PrintQ>\w+).(?<Action>ADDED|DELETED|UPDATED\b)(?<Junk2>\s\w+\s\w+\s)(?<User>\w+)"
```

Works:

```sh
$Datereg = "(?<Date>\d{2}\s[ADFJMNOS][a-z]{2,8}\s[12][0-9]{3}\b)"
$TimeReg = "(?<Time>\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s"
$ErrorIDReg = "(?<ErrorID>[VPSa]{2,4}\d{4}[A-Z])"
$Junk1Reg = "(?<Junk>.<.*?>.*?\s)"
$PrintQreg = "(?<PrintQ>\w+)"
$ActionReg = "(?<Action>\s\w+)"
$Junk2Reg = "(?<Junk2>\s\w+\s\w+)"
$UserReg = "(?<User>\s\w+\s)"

$regex = $Datereg + $TimeReg + $ErrorIDReg + $Junk1Reg + $PrintQreg + $ActionReg + $Junk2Reg + $UserReg
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the tokens of interest are *mostly* space-separated tokens, I suggest a different approach, based primarily on `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split):

```
Get-Content logfile.txt | ForEach-Object { 

  # Split the line into tokens by whitespace.
  $tokens = -split $_

  # Get the action value.
  # Use the 4th token *from the end* (-4) to account for the fact that
  # some lines have an extra word - 'CONFIGURATION' - inserted before the
  # action value.
  $action = $tokens[-4]
 
  if ($action -in 'UPDATED', 'DELETED', 'ADDED') {
    # Construct and output an object from the tokens.
    [pscustomobject] @{ 
      Date = $tokens[0..2] -join ' '
      Time = $tokens[3]
      ErrorId = $tokens[4]
      PrintQ = $tokens[7]
      Action = $action
      User = $tokens[-1] # user is always the last token
    }
  }

}
```

<sup>Note: PowerShell's operators are generally case-*insensitive*; if you need case-*sensitive* matching, place a `c` before the operator name, such as `-ceq` and `-cin`.</sup>

With your sample input, the above outputs:

```
Date    : 09 Dec 2020
Time    : 12:59:28
ErrorId : VPSa0217I
PrintQ  : PRINTQUEUE1
Action  : ADDED
User    : op9p99

Date    : 09 Dec 2020
Time    : 13:00:22
ErrorId : VPSa0219I
PrintQ  : PRINTQUEUE1
Action  : UPDATED
User    : op9p99

Date    : 09 Dec 2020
Time    : 14:20:59
ErrorId : VPSa0217I
PrintQ  : PRINTQUEUE1
Action  : DELETED
User    : op9p99
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this set of regexes:

```
$log = @"
09 Dec 2020 12:59:28 VPSa0217I <CREQ0009        > PRINTQUEUE1 ADDED BY USER op9p99
09 Dec 2020 13:00:22 VPSa0219I <CREQ0011        > PRINTQUEUE1 CONFIGURATION UPDATED BY USER op9p99
09 Dec 2020 14:20:59 VPSa0217I <CREQ0014        > PRINTQUEUE1 DELETED BY USER op9p99
"@

$DateReg = "(?<Date>\d{2}\s[ADFJMNOS][a-z]{2,8}\s[12][0-9]{3}\b)"
$TimeReg = "(?<Time>\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s"
$ErrorIDReg = "(?<ErrorID>[VPSa]{2,4}\d{4}[A-Z])\s"
$Junk1Reg = "(?<Junk><[^>]+>)\s"
$PrintQreg = "(?<PrintQ>\w+)\s(?!CONFIGURATION\s)"
$ActionReg = "(?<Action>\w+)\s"
$Junk2Reg = "(?<Junk2>\w+\s\w+)\s"
$UserReg = "(?<User>\w+)"

$regex = $Datereg + $TimeReg + $ErrorIDReg + $Junk1Reg + $PrintQreg + $ActionReg + $Junk2Reg + $UserReg

$log -split "`n" | Foreach-Object { if ($_ -match $regex) {"Matched line: $_"}}
```

Which outputs:

```
Matched line: 09 Dec 2020 12:59:28 VPSa0217I <CREQ0009        > PRINTQUEUE1 ADDED BY USER op9p99
Matched line: 09 Dec 2020 14:20:59 VPSa0217I <CREQ0014        > PRINTQUEUE1 DELETED BY USER op9p99
```

The primary tweak was to use a zero-width assertion called `negative lookahead` to make sure that after the `PrintQ` text there is not the text `CONFIGURATION` . I also tweaked your `Junk1Reg` to use `<[^>]+>`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Looks like this just ignores the whole line below. Causing my script to error out.
09 Dec 2020 13:00:22 VPSa0219I <CREQ0011        > PRINTQUEUE1 CONFIGURATION UPDATED BY USER op9p99

Comment: I think this site might be better for powershell regex. But when I plug all that in, it does match add and deleted. Skips the entire config line. Feel free to scrap how I did it if it's easier. I kinda just hacked my way to get that far. lol

https://regexr.com/